# Queries on GKE Autoscaling

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, autoscaling

I have both `Node Auto Provisioning` and `Autoscaling` enabled on a `GKE` Cluster. Few queries on Auto Scaling.

For `AutoScaling`, the minimum nodes are 1 and the maximum number of nodes is 2. Few queries based on this setup.

I set the number of nodes to 0 using `gcloud` command

```
gcloud container clusters resize cluster-gke-test --node-pool pool-1  --num-nodes 0 --zone us-central1-c
```

Now I can see the message that `Pods` are unscheduleable

```
 Your cluster has one or more unschedulable pods.
```

Following are my queries

1. Since `autoscaling` is enabled , the nodes should have been automatically spawned in order to run these `Pods` . But I don't see this happening . Is this not the expected behavior ?
2. Auto Scaling does not work when we reduce the number of nodes manually?
3. Auto Scaling works based on load only. If there are requests which cannot be handled by existing nodes then only it will launch new nodes. The minimum number of nodes for Node autoscaling to work should be always greater than zero?

Comment: You set the number of node to 0 with a --num-nodes 3 ?? I'm sorry, I'm lost there!! And when you talk about Autoscaling, it's node autoscaling, not HPA (Horizontal Pod Autoscaller).

Comment: Sorry..typo . Updated it and yes it is Node AutoScaling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's a [documented limitation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler#limitations). If your node pool is set to 0, there isn't auto scaling from 0
2. Yes it works as long as you don't manually scale to 0.
3. It's also [documented](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler#how_cluster_autoscaler_works). The node pool scale according with the request. If a Pod is unschedulable because of a lack of resource, and the max-node isn't reach, a new node is provisioned and the pod deployed.

you can set 0 to min-nodes, but you must at least have 1 node active in the cluster, on anther node pool

> If you specify a minimum of zero nodes, an idle node pool can scale down completely. However, at least one node must always be available in the cluster to run system Pods.

Comment: Thanks . Does auto scaling will work when we manually stop  a GKE Node ? This is for the scenario when there is no load but the number of nodes became less than minimum of nodes after stopping a node?

Comment: For the above scenario it did not launch new nodes even when the number of running nodes is less than the number of nodes that should run as per auto provisioning